# cannot define EventHandler as event

Tags: c#, events, eventhandler

I need an `IDictionary<T,K>` that raises an event whenever an `item` is added via the `Add` method. But the event that is raised should depend on the key of `item`, i.e. if I add `("hello","world")` to such a dictionary, the "hello"-event should be raised, and if I add `("world","hello")`, then the "world"-event should be raised.

So I tried to implement this and ended up with

```
class EventDictionary<T,K> : IDictionary<T,K>
{
    private IDictionary<T,K> _internalDic;
    private IDictionary<T, EventHandler> _onAddHandlers;

    public EventHandler OnAdd(T key)
    {
        if (!_onAddHandlers.ContainsKey(key))
            _onAddHandlers[key] = null;
        return _onAddHandlers[key];
    }

    public void Add(T key, K value)
    {
        _internalDic.Add(key, value);
        OnAdd(key)?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<T, K> item)
    {
        _internalDic.Add(item);
        OnAdd(item.Key)?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    ... // implementing the other methods of IDictionary<T,K>
}
```

This compiles - as long as I don't add the `event` keyword:

```
private IDictionary<T, event EventHandler> _onAddHandlers; // syntax error
```

OR

```
public event EventHandler OnAdd(T key) { ... } // syntax error
```

**Have I missed something? How can I make the `OnAdd` event handlers (all of them) `event`s?**

Comment: @itsme86 That would also not compile, unlike the OP's original code, which will work just fine.

Comment: event is not a type. Its a keyword. EventHandler is the type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to have a dynamic number of events on your type.  Events, just like other members (fields, methods, properties) need to be statically defined at compile time.  So you can have your dictionary of delegates, and you can add/remove delegates from the dictionary, and invoke those delegates when you want, but they won't be events on that class; they'll need to go through methods, as you've done so far.

If, instead, you just want to have a *single* event where the signature of the event is one where it accepts a parameter of type `T`, then you simply need to use an appropriate delegate, instead of `EventHandler`, when declaring your event:

```
public event Action<T> OnAdd; // syntax error
```

Comment: But you could use a generic EventHandler to have a similar effect

Comment: @YairHalberstadt You can have a *single* event that accepts a `T` as a parameter.  You can't have the event name/definition be dynamic.

Comment: Yes. But depending on what he wants to do, it might well be sufficient

Comment: Is there some other way to prevent outside users of my `EventHandler`s to overwrite the invocation list by using `=`? Or to make sure that only the `EventDictionary` class can call `Invoke` on them?

Comment: @Kjara The dictionary is private, so an external caller cannot invoke it or assign any values to it at all, unless you expose some other public member that does either of those things (or exposes the dictionary).  So all you need to do is keep the dictionary private and only expose methods that add/remove handlers, and nothing else (which is just what an `event` exposes.